# Form's ClientSize giving weird results on set

Tags: c#, winforms, size

I've encountered an annoying problem:
When I set my form's `ClientSize` property to match `300*300`, the size indeed does change, but it's totally not `300*300`. Actually, it's not even `x*x` but rather `x*y`, since its width is greater than its height.

This is a picture of my program after setting my form's `ClientSize = new Size(300, 300);` and creating a black `Panel` inside it with size `250*250`.

[image: Form.ClientSize is not a square?]

I measured them with photoshop and the black `Panel` was indeed `250*250`, whereas the form's client size was more like `280*260` or so.

Why is this happening, have I understood the `ClientSize` property's meaning wrong?
If so, how can I get the actual "drawing area" of my form to accurately match the size I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check have you set `min` or `max` size of your `form`.

Comment: Had `MaximumSize` set to something around `306*306` somewhere deep down in my code... Didn't think of that, thanks! :)